# Как сверстать фон, нарезанный по диагонали

Tags: html, css, background

Как сверстать фон, нарезанный по диагонали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Нарезать скошенный кусок фона первого блока с фоном второго блока http://prntscr.com/evf2fz.

Нарезать фоны в png с прозрачностью той части,что перекошена и задать отрицательные маргины.

Побить дизайнера

Comment: Копирайтера тоже побить за такой текст.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, причем копирайтера надо бить сильнее..

Comment: @Игорь вот этой книгой бить https://book.glvrd.ru/

Answer (score 3):

Это можно реализовать через псевдоэлементы `:before` или `:after`, которые абсолютно позиционируются со 100% шириной и высотой, а также свойства `transform`. Значение `z-index` у псевдоэлемента должно быть меньше. Таким образом нижний срез будет под основным блоком. Вот пример такой реализации:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: lightgray;
  background: url('https://wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main2/201727/1499320136595dcf486c76e6.19078340.jpg') center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.page1,
.page2,
.page3,
.page4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.page1 {
  z-index: 4;
  background: chocolate;
}

.page2 {
  z-index: 3;
  background: burlywood;
}

.page3 {
  z-index: 2;
  background: pink;
}

.page4 {
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}

.page1:after,
.page2:after,
.page3:after,
.page4:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.page1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewY(3.6deg);
}

.page2:after {
  z-index: -2;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewY(-3.6deg);
}

.page3:after {
  z-index: -3;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skewY(3.6deg);
}

.page4:after {
  z-index: -4;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewY(-3.6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="page1">
</div>
<div class="page2">
</div>
<div class="page3">
</div>
<div class="page4">
</div>
```

Comment: с картинкой то есть с не однородным фоном не канает

Comment: ну так есть с картинкой ? или нет ?

Comment: картинка протухла на верно ..там такие пропасти ...ужос

Comment: нету там картинок - по крайней мере у меня ..могу скрин показать

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием свойства `clip-path` для маскирования в CSS, которое применяется ко всем элементам HTML. Плюс (+) этого варианта в том, что теперь мы можем использовать не только сплошную заливку секций одним цветом, но а также и графический фон `background`, который будет отсекаться под нужным нам углом, какой мы укажем для этой секции. Вот пример такой реализации:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: lightgray;
  background: url('https://wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main2/201727/1499320136595dcf486c76e6.19078340.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.page1,
.page2,
.page3,
.page4,
.page4__bg,
.page5,
.page6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.page1 {
  background: chocolate;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 74%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 74%, 0% 100%);
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.page2 {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 13%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 13%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
}

.page3 {
  background: pink;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 23%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 84%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 23%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 84%);
  min-height: 120vh;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 170vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}

.page4 {
  background: pink;
}

.page4__bg {
  background: burlywood url('https://i.imgur.com/nPCx8lS.png') center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 84%, 0% 100%);
}

.page4:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  background: burlywood;
  top: -50vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.page5 {
  background: pink;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  height: 50vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}

.page6 {
  background: lavender;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.page6 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30%;
  right: 70%;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="page1"><span>Котики</span>
</div>
<div class="page2">
</div>
<div class="page3"><span>Лапули, правда?</span>
</div>
<div class="page4">
  <div class="page4__bg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page5"><span>Какой милашка!</span>
</div>
<div class="page6"><span>The end :)</span>
</div>
```